# ceiling fixture wires

Tags: electrical, ceiling, light-fixture

meant to change a lightbulb and the whole light
fixture came down. was confused and didnt pay attention when i took out a wire. any help really appreciated. from the ceiling i see 1 black and 1 white wire connected and 2 brown wires. on the fixture one black and one white, which were connected to the brown ones im guessing. i wasnt thinking and jumped the gun. whats the easiest way to figure this out? thanks in advance[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typical switch loop, where you have a power cable coming into the box, and another cable acts as an out and back in, though the switch, for the hot leg.

[image]

Connect the black and white of your fixture to the two whites in either configuration. (Technically, the white coming back from the switch is your "hot", so connect that to black if you know which is which. It should've been labelled by the installer.)

Comment: so i should test the two light brown wires to see which is the hot one and thatll will be the one to attach the black one to?

Comment: I don't see any brown wires. I see two dirty white wires, and two blacks connected with a nut. Yes, you could test like that. With basic light fixtures polarity often doesn't matter, though.

Comment: if you look closely you can also see a bare wire, you will need to connect the bare wire from the fixture to that.